# How to build Kernel for Android phone from scratch?

Tags: android, kernel

How to build a kernel from scratch for my android phone?
It doesn't have its source code available anywhere...
But i know its Chip set (MSM7627a) for which the code is available at codeaurora.org, can that be used?

Now they have source code till only android version 4.2.1, is there anyway that i can update it to latest version?(4.4)

Can I use the general source code from kernel/msm to effect the changes?

And is it possible that I can directly use the source code from the Kernel/msm tree as it says its a starting point for MSM chip sets

Comment: It really depends on your phone, or the manufacturer to be more specific. Can you tell us the specific type of phone you have? Is it a Samsung or a HTC? Which detailed model version? This would make it much easier to answer this question, cause many manufacturers have made their own changes to the kernel. Thanks.

Comment: Its a chinese phone K-Touch K757 with qualcomm chipset specified above. I dont believe they would have made any changes to kernel...:)